# Spring cannot load java based configuration

Tags: spring, solr

I want to create a Solr data import handler using Spring as the Ioc. When I try to invoke the handler from Solr, I got below error

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to load bean class: com.yoox.shanghai.AppConfig; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource **[com/my/app/AppConfig.class]** cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

Note the path printed in the message. It looks like it is using a relative path. I have no idea what is the cause.

I am using the [Java based container configuration](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-java), and the compilation passes. And my code works with JUnit4.

```
appCtx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppConfig.class);
```

Comment: How are you loading the Spring context? Please add the relevant code/configuration.

Comment: Does `resources.AppConfig.class` acually compile? This does not match `com/my/app/AppConfig.class`.

Comment: @LutzHorn, thx :) I pasted the wrong code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I googled for a long time, but could not find any answer about how spring resolve the class path by default. But I found people are trying to explicitly set the class loader, so I tried.

```
appCtx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
appCtx.setClassLoader(this.getClass().getClassLoader());
appCtx.register(AppConfig.class);
appCtx.refresh();
```

And it works :D

However I am not satisfied with this answer. I hope some one can point out what's wrong with my class loading logic.

Comment: I couldn't find setClassLoader in spring 3.4! how did you get to that setter?

Comment: If the [document](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/context/annotation/AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.html) is correct, it should be there. But I think *Spring* is just too big. I turned to Google's **Guice**.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you import AppConfig properly? Otherwise make sure that the class has really been deployed (check the deployment directory).

Comment: Yes, I do checked, the class is there. The key to this problem is how spring find the classes. I tried to check my classpath value, but I do not know where to look at :(

Comment: The Spring configuration files are normally classpath resources stored in the `src/main/resources` folder. During the build process, they are copied into the `WEB-INF/classes` directory. Are you using Maven?

Comment: yes, i did. I am using Ivy to control dependencies. I tried to remove Ivy, and use Maven. But in Eclipse it seems won't work :(